# php-fpm[2593] general protection - could someone explain?

Tags: php, php-fpm

Could somebody explain what this error means?

What is `ip`, `sp` and what does the numbers stand for?

If I `grep -i "general protection ip" messages*` I get below output. It is happening quite often and we need to restart php, db2 etc to make things work again. Not sure if below is related to it but we need to investiga it too.

```
messages-20121124:Nov 22 09:01:54 tscedum01 kernel: [1666210.553430] php-fpm[10480] general protection ip:6278f0 sp:7fffa5d318b0 error:0 in php-fpm[400000+5fb000]
messages-20121124:Nov 23 08:25:52 tscedum01 kernel: [1750448.768410] php-fpm[28793] general protection ip:6278f0 sp:7fff2f7d1210 error:0 in php-fpm[400000+5fb000]
messages-20121124:Nov 23 08:47:47 tscedum01 kernel: [1751763.477525] php-fpm[2520] general protection ip:6278f0 sp:7fffe194fe60 error:0 in php-fpm[400000+5fb000]
messages-20121124:Nov 23 08:47:47 tscedum01 kernel: [1751763.523385] php-fpm[2602] general protection ip:6278f0 sp:7fffe194fe60 error:0 in php-fpm[400000+5fb000]
```

Answer (score 1):

It means PHP crashed.

Visit [PHP's bugs page](https://bugs.php.net/) for more information on [determining why it crashed](https://bugs.php.net/bugs-generating-backtrace.php), and [how to report the bug](https://bugs.php.net/how-to-report.php) (if it wasn't already reported and/or fixed).

Comment: I cannot see anywhere what the numbers mean. Is it let's say memory address? It would be helpful to know.

Comment: ip: instruction pointer  sp: stack pointer.  It's telling you where it was when it crashed.  to answer your question 5 years later :)